# why different qquickframebufferobject show the same opengl output?

Tags: qt, opengl

I want to Integrate multiple custom OpenGL rendering with Qt Quick via QQuickFramebufferObject, and I create three different QQuickFramebufferObject used to integrate the three custom OpenGL. But the result is that different QQuickFramebufferObject show the only one same custom OpenGL rendering.

Answer (score 0):

You must take problem with binding buffer. Make sure you bind the corresponding one for each render.

Comment: yes, you find the key to the question, but what is the right way to binding buffer?